# Alternative to second-level nested correlated subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need an alternative to the following SQL query. The reason being that some earlier versions of Oracle database (prior to 12C, not sure which exactly) don't support the 2nd-level nested correlated subquery, where Oracle 12C does.

```
select 
    a.val1,
    a.val2,
    (
        select /* select the top single-field record from the inner select 
                statement */
            * 
        from 
        (
            select 
                b.val1
            from 
                tb2 b
            where 
                b.val2 < a.val3 and b.val3 = a.val4
            order by 
                b.val2 desc /* order by b.val2 desc in order to allow 
                                the outer select statement to obtain the 
                                largest b.val2 value */
        ) 
        where rownum = 1
    ) as someName
from
    tb1 a;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `keep`:

```
select a.val1, a.val2,
       (select max(b.val1) keep (dense_rank first order by val2 desc)
        from tb2 b
        where b.val2 < a.val3 and b.val3 = a.val4
       ) as someName
from tb1 a;
```

`keep` is powerful syntax in Oracle, which is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm).  Essentially, this gets the first value of `val1` based on the ordering by `val2`.  This is very similar to what `first_value(val1) over (order by val2 desc)`does -- except `keep` acts as an aggregation function.

Comment: Would you mind please explaining to me what `select max(b.val1) keep (dense_rank first order by val2 desc)` will do? From what I could gather by doing a quick google search, it seems like it would get all the row(s) with the highest b.val2, and if there are multiple such rows then it would select the one with the largest b.val1 value, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
select a.val1, a.val2, b.val1 from tb1 a
inner join
tb2 b on (b.val2 < a.val3 and b.val3 = a.val4) 
order by b.val2 desc;
```

or

```
 select a.val1, a.val2, b.val1 from tb1 a
inner join
(select val1 from tb2) b on (b.val2 < a.val3 and b.val3 = a.val4)
order by b.val2 desc;
```

Let me know in case you face any issues